# How to access https://storage.googleapis.com/modelzoo?

Tags: tensorflow, google-cloud-platform

I notice that some pretrain-ed models are stored on https://storage.googleapis.com/modelzoo. For example:

- InceptionV1.pb
  https://storage.googleapis.com/modelzoo/InceptionV1.pb
- InceptionV1-labels
  https://storage.googleapis.com/modelzoo/InceptionV1-labels.txt

I guess there are a lot of models have been stored on the website. My question is how to access this `mdoelzoo` to these models.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [wget](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/) to download the files locally where you can refer to them later, e.g:

```
wget https://storage.googleapis.com/modelzoo/InceptionV1.pb
```

If wget is not installed you can install it as per the following [instructions](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-to-install-wget-togetrid-of-error-bash-wget-command-not-found/).